# Oracle Grid Control Notification for Data Guard failures

Tags: oracle

Does anyone know a way to configure a Grid Control notification rule for a failure of the SQL APPLY process on a logical standby database? I'd really like an email notification that the SQL APPLY process has encountered an error and is no longer applying redo to the logical standby.